# How to compute the inverse laplace transform of this term? ${-{{3}\over{10}}s-{{1}\over{5}}\over{(s+1)^2+1}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, partial-fractions, initial-value-problems

So, I have been asked to solve $y'-2y=e^{-t} *cos(t)$ where $y(0)=-2.$

I applied the Laplace transform, getting 
$$\mathcal{L}(y)={{-2s^2-3s-3}\over{(s-2)((s+1)^2+1)}}$$

I set up a partial fraction decomposition of the form
$${{-2s^2-3s-3}\over{(s-2)((s+1)^2+1)}}={{A}\over{(s-2)}}+{{Bs+C}\over{(s+1)^2+1}}$$

I solved for values of the constants (and checked them using a solver to avoid mistakes) and I ended up with

$$\mathcal{L}(y)={-{{17}\over{10}}\over{(s-2)}}+{-{{3}\over{10}}s-{{1}\over{5}}\over{(s+1)^2+1}}$$

Obviously, the inverse laplace transform of the first term is $-{{17}\over{10}}e^{2t}$, however, I get stuck trying to find the inverse laplace transform of the second term.

It resembles the form ${{s-a}\over{(s-a)^2+b^2}}=e^{at}cos(bt)$, but I cannot figure out how to wrestle this function fully into this form.

What can I do to get this term into a form that I can handle?

Comment: Do they *force* you to use Laplace transforms to solve this? 'Cause much simpler and shorter methods exist...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. Differential equations final tomorrow! I'm thrilled.

Comment: Here is a tip for your final: $y'-2y$ is almost an exact derivative, "almost" because $(e^{-2t}y)'=e^{-2t}(y'-2y)$ hence your equation is actually $(e^{-2t}y)'=e^{-3t}\cos t$ and the solutions you are after are $$y(t)=y(0)e^{2t}+e^{2t}\int_0^te^{-3s}\cos sds,$$ and if you can identify the integral, you are done.

Comment: use the complex partial fraction decomposition instead of the real one

Comment: @user1952009 Not permitted to.

Comment: @Did We are asked to solve it this particular way, to demonstrate out ability to do so, unfortunately.

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans instead of saying "not permitted to" just try it, you'll see that the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{as+b}{c(s+e)^2+d}$ is obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal{L}(y)={-{{3}\over{10}}s-{{1}\over{5}}\over{(s+1)^2+1}}$

you want to get this into the form.${a(s+1) + b}\over{(s+1)^2+1}$

At which point:

$y = ae^{-t}\cos t + b e^{-t} \sin t$

${-\frac 3{10}(s+1) + \frac 1{10}}\over{(s+1)^2+1}$

Comment: I understand why it would help to get it into this form, but how did you do so? I'm missing something in your algebra.

Comment: When I show it to you, you are going to shake your head and say, I should have seen that... $-\frac3{10} s - \frac 15 =  -\frac3{10} s - \frac 3{10} + \frac 1{10} = -\frac3{10} (s +1) + \frac 1{10}$

Comment: Well, you weren't wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may write
$$
{-{{3}\over{10}}s-{{1}\over{5}}\over{(s+1)^2+1}}=-\frac3{10}{(s+1)\over{(s+1)^2+1}}+\frac1{10}{1\over{(s+1)^2+1}}
$$ then one may apply the properties of the inverse Laplace transform to each term (have a look [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf)).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps write
$(s+1)^2+1
= s^2+2s+2
=(s-a)(s-b)
$
and doing partial fraction
decomposition.

$a$ and $b$
are complex, of course.

Comment: I'd like to avoid complex numbers, since it is out of the scope of my course.

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans it is impossible to avoid complex numbers in the Laplace transform : since it uses the complex numbers it is very first definition, so check out your course again